# CDI: Why am I getting two instances of javax.ejb.Singleton in my unit test?

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, cdi, jboss-arquillian

Got a class `MyService` annotated with `@javax.ejb.Singleton`.

```java
@Singleton
public class MyService() { 
    ..
}
```

The unit test (Arquillian) below fails (1 and 2):

```java
@Inject private MyService myService1;
@Inject private MyService myService2;

@Test
public void singletonScopedTest() {

    // 1
    assertEquals(myService1, myService2);

    // 2
    assertTrue(myService1== myService2);
}
```

The same test applied to `@ApplicationScoped` *produced* beans will pass.

**Question**

Why the test fails for `@Singleton` but pass for `@ApplicationScoped` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects that are @Injected for EJBs are proxies, not the object instances themselves.

Your unit tests are comparing the proxy objects.

Comment: Just for the record, `@ApplicationScoped` will use proxy as well.